# How to download S3 bucket files without AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-s3, file-sharing

We use S3 bucket to store the artifacts built by Jenkins server runs on AWS.

We are looking for a solution for company employees to download these artifacts easily.

Are there any AWS services and documentation that we can use to implement this, thanks.

Security requirements:
1. The S3 buckets should be configured for encryption using KMS managed key.
2. Download access should be available only for authorized company employees.
3. Users downloading the final artifacts should authenticate with their company domain credentials to access the artifacts share.
4. The access should be over an encrypted network communication channel.

Comment: You could deploy a simple app which uses a single AWS account with access to those files and generates "pre-signed" URLs  so that users can use generated links for (very?) limited period of time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Identity Providers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers.html) with AWS IAM to manage user access

> With an identity provider (IdP), you can manage your user identities outside of AWS and give these external user identities permissions to use AWS resources in your account. This is useful if your organization already has its own identity system, such as a corporate user directory.

[AWS Transfer for SFTP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/what-is-aws-transfer-for-sftp.html) may also be suitable for your requirements, with or without IAM Identity Providers:

> AWS Transfer for SFTP (AWS SFTP) is a fully managed AWS service that enables you to transfer files over Secure File Transfer Protocol (SFTP), into and out of Amazon S3 buckets. SFTP is also known as Secure Shell (SSH) File Transfer Protocol.